# Align element to the Grid

Tags: css, html, alignment, zurb-foundation

i am building a new website http://ba-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/antonio/ using **Foundation**

what i want is to align the **red bordered** elements as you can see from the screen. what i'm doing wrong? Ther's something missing?

[image]

HTML:

```
<!-- ***START CONTENT*** -->
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-3 columns logo">
      <img src="img/logo_BA.png" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-12 columns navbar">
      <div class="magellan-container" style="background-color:#fff !important;" data-magellan-expedition="fixed" data-options="destination_threshold:65;throttle_delay:0;" >
         <dl class="sub-nav">
            <dd data-magellan-arrival="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></dd>
            <dd data-magellan-arrival="architektur"><a href="#architektur">Architektur</a></dd>
            <dd data-magellan-arrival="lage"><a href="#lage">Lage</a></dd>
            <dd data-magellan-arrival="wohnungen"><a href="#wohnungen">Wohnungen</a></dd>
            <dd data-magellan-arrival="galerie"><a href="#galerie">Galerie</a></dd>
            <dd data-magellan-arrival="kontakt"><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></dd>
            <dd data-magellan-arrival="impressum"><a href="#impressum">Impressum</a></dd>
         </dl>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-12 columns slider">
      <img src="img/slider1.png" width="1529" height="893" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row homerow" style="background-image: url('img/bg_section.png'); background-size: 100%;">
   <div class="large-4 columns">
      <h1 class="home">Architektur</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">Lorem Ipsum. Proin<br>gravida nibh.</h2>
      <p class="testo-home">vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="large-4 columns">
      <h1 class="home">Lage</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">Lorem Ipsum. Proin<br>gravida nibh</h2>
      <p class="testo-home">vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="large-4 columns">
      <h1 class="home">Wohnungen</h1>
   </div>
   <h2 class="subtitle">Lorem Ipsum. Proin<br>gravida nibh</h2>
   <p class="testo-home">vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum. vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum.</p>
   <div class="large12 columns">
      <img src="img/place.jpg" />
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* **GENERAL STYLES** */

body {
  background-color: #efe7d6;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

h1 {
  color: #009ee0;
  text-indent: left;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* END GENERAL STYLES */

.logo {
  float: right !important;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.home {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.row.homerow {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.testo-home {
  font-size: 0.785em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: To align the grid elements add an id `id="grid"` to the div containing 3 columns and add margin of 20px. or play around with diff values. Hope that helps!